# Configure terminal dimensions to show as Lines x Columns

Tags: macos, terminal

In my terminal, when I ask to show Dimensions (profiles -> window -> dimensions), it shows the dimensions as Columns x Lines, but when I use `resize -s 25 200`, I am actually resizing as Lines x Columns, so I would like the dimensions to display in the same way.

Is there any way to get the Dimensions in the title to appear in the same order as the parameters in `resize -s`?

Answer (score 1):

There is no straightforward way to change the Terminal option, you can define your own resizing function though to accomplish this (you may want to add error handling if required):

```
tsize() {
     resize -s ${2:-25} ${1:-80}
}
```

Put this into your `.bashrc` (and deploy to all your computers if you are using several).